# After installing ruby2.0.0 it still says "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0

I have installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev ruby1.9.1
mkdir rubysource
cd rubysource
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

The result of ruby-v now is:

> ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

But when I change in my rails project directory and try to start the server (rails s) or I try "rails -v" the answer is always:
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

The Gemfile is:

```
ruby '2.0.0'

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.1'
gem 'capistrano', '2.14.1'
gem "therubyracer", '~> 0.11.4'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.8.0'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2'
gem 'sitemap_generator', '3.4'
gem 'whenever', '0.7.3', :require => false
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.0.beta4"
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'protected_attributes'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'faker', '0.9.5', :require => false
#  gem 'ruby-debug19', '0.11.6'
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.0.1"
  gem 'debugger'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
end

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Why doesn't rails recognize the new ruby version?

Comment: Maybe try `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: You're not using RVM, by the looks of it?

Comment: do you use `rvm`? if yes have you a reloaded shell? or try `rvm reload` in current one

Comment: `rails` script in the bin directory still uses old version of ruby in shebang - see output of `gem environment` for details.

Comment: bundle exec rails s gives the same answer:Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

Comment: gem environment:RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/mathias/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/

Comment: you could manually edit `rails` script, but that is not recommended, to find location of it type `whereis rails`.  Better option is to reinstall gems and update `$PATH` with new gems executables location.

Comment: A couple other things to try: `ruby -S rails s` or `script/rails s` or remove old ruby gem dirs from `PATH`.

Comment: log out and back in to make sure your shell sees the new path?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have another ruby installed.

I suggest you to use RVM : https://rvm.io/

It is the proper way to deal with multiple ruby environment.

Comment: It is but one of ways to manage rubies. Other ones: rbenv and chruby.

Comment: Thanks, but If possible I would go without rvm.

Comment: If you don't need multiple ruby, you can just remove the old one.

Answer (score -1):

If you use RVM, then do in terminal: `/bin/bash --login` (for Ubuntu 13.04)
Else do `sudo apt-get remove ruby` and install ruby 2.0.0 (but i'm suggest use Ruby Version Manager)